# What are the Differences between these runcompilation,cache management and index management?

Tags: magento-1.7, cache, index, compiler

I am using Magento, but manytimes mychanges could not make anything in results..

So,i got some answers from stackoverflow and some other sites as use cache management, index management and run compilation.

So among these options,what is the use of each one?

Please help me to understand..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compilation takes all the classes and files required and puts them in one directory for quicker lookup when going through the code.

Indexing places data from quite few database tables in one or two tables (per indexer) most of the times applying further logic to the data before putting it in the database tables for quicker database lookups and processing.

Caching stores information that has already been processed. For instance the first time a magento page is loaded it does several things:
 Collect all the module config.xml files and merge them. Get all the layout files and merge them. Built the blocks and created HTML for them.

In the cache the merged config, merged layout and block HTML is saved, so next time this page is loaded it can ask the cache system for the info instead of processing everything.

From my experience. If you often update/change magento code stay away from compilation it takes a lot of time&pain for little gain.

Comment: Very very effective and clean explanation  @Marijn Schot ...Thank you so much..

Comment: As you said, if i disable these options magento takes time to do a task right  @Marijn Schot?

Comment: @user3804631 yes it will take longer without these options enabled

Comment: but the compilation part only brings <50ms if you already have a good configured opcache(which you always should use)

Answer (score 1):

Compilation is a process to optimize file access on php classes in magento.

In a usual environment you should not activate it, as the php solutions like opcache solve this problem perfectly with less problems and side effect.

caches are what the name says, parts which get saved (mostly for a limited time) for the next run, because its unlikely they will return a different result.

index management is something similar to compilation, but not for php classes, but for database data.
While magento is possible to work without the flat tables, there is no alternate way for the other indexes, so they should be up to date, or you will have old data.
Here it is says, they have 2 modes, update on save, and manual update.
For update on save you should have no problems as long the modules are all cleanly build.